# SWIG [C++ to LISP(CFFI)] how to get array in C++ wrap into CFFI list?

Tags: c++, common-lisp, wrapper, swig, cffi

I have a simple C++ function that returns an array of int (as a pointer (int*)) and when the wrapping is done CFFI see it as a pointer. It's logical but what I want is CFFI see it as a list. Is there a way to do it in SWIG configuration?

```
int* myfunction(){
     int tab[5] = {2, 5, 4, 6, 10} ;
     ...
     return tab;
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: 1. `tab` is an array, not a list. 2. Using the pointer you're returning is undefined. (And perhaps 3: A C++ array is nothing like a Lisp list.)

Comment: Yes, sorry the post wasn't correct, I meant array.

Comment: The code is broken, because the pointer returned becomes invalid after leaving the function.